# how to share sounds with a long click?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to share several audios from my raw folder to another application (whatsapp, gmail, etc). Through a button, if I click on it the audio sound, and if I keep pressed I want the option to share. As I have seen on the internet a way of sharing a file is creating an Intent, but creating it within the method of holding down, I get an error in getPackageName. How could I solve this? Here part of my code:

```
final MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cristobalmasgrande);
Button button1 =(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sound1.start();
    }
});

button1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Intent compartirAudio = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        compartirAudio.setType("audio/*");
        compartirAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + araujomio)); //Error on getPackageName()
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartirAudio, "Compartir vía"));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `this.getPackageName()`, `this`is the `OnLongClickListener` instance. It has no method named `getPackage()`.
You have several options, e.g:

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + v.getContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/" + araujomio));
```

or

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + araujomio));
```